# What is the "Load Loose Files" checkbox in the Data Files dialog?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the Data Files dialog of the Skyrim launcher, there's a checkbox titled "Load Loose Files" which is disabled by default. **What does this checkbox do?**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'm not certain, but I believe it means to load data files that aren't contained in an esp or esm file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Fambida wrote in the comments, "data files that aren't contained in an esp or esm file." - an example would be some added/changed textures like this mod: http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=193  -- basically a couple of .dds files